# how to change docker registry default from docker.io to another address in centos

Tags: linux, docker, centos, docker-registry

I want to change my docker registry address from docker.io to another remote server . I want to change in in my docker service config file . in ubuntu it is in this file

> /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service

and the parameter is

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --registry-mirror=exampleurl

but i do not khow how can i change it in centos 6

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/#configure-the-docker-daemon

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to `DOCKER_OPTS` in `/etc/default/docker`. That file will get sourced by `/etc/init.d/docker`.

Comment: thanks a lot  hek2mgl . could you tell me what is the line i should add to this file?

Comment: I mean `/etc/default/docker`

Comment: Add `DOCKER_OPTS="--registry-mirror='exampleurl'"` to that file

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` check in this path once 
or else do a find `sudo find / -iname docker.service` and edit the file.